# How to "put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list"?

Tags: terminal, apt, pidgin

**machine**:
Toshiba MK1646GSX, intel atom CPU@1.60Ghz, 2048Mb. 32bit.

**OS**: 
LINUX LITE 3.8

i was trying to install the PIDGIN dependencies:

```
 ~> sudo apt-get build-dep pidgin
```

and then i got this instead of installing the `build-dep`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your     sources.list
```

so i searched and i found sources say that i should `rm -rf the sources.list`, and then `apt-get update` and the list will create itself.
the results were not good and like what i expected, the list didn't create itself.
after that i made a new list with the same content, i tried to make sure about every line and does it own `deb-src`.
all lines are correct.
but the Error still exits when i try to install the `build-dep`.
what to do?

---

sources.list copied from the justpaste link:

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse


###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse


###### Ubuntu Partner Repos
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ xenial partner
```

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get update` before `sudo apt-get build-dep pidgin`?

Comment: How does your `sources.list` look like?

Comment: @Freddy yes i did, i said that already in the text.

Comment: @guillermochamorro https://justpaste.it/33tq1

Comment: Uncomment `# deb-src...`

Comment: @guillermochamorro done. i updated the sources, and then i installed the dependencies. it works, thank you man.

Comment: please don't link to external sites for short text fragments.  paste them into your question (and format as code).  i've fixed that for you this time.

Answer (score 10):

Uncomment the `deb-src` lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```bsh
sudo sed -i 's/# deb-src/deb-src/' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
```

Comment: IMO `apt update` requirement should be included in the error message, not everybody knows internals that well to see it is necessary after sources file editing.

Answer (score 0):

**`software-properties-gtk` option "Source code"**

From the GUI, you can run:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

then under the "Ubuntu Software" tab click "Source code":

[image]

This has added some `deb-src` lines under `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and now I can do `sudo apt-get build-dep <package>`.

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.

See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/496549/error-you-must-put-some-source-uris-in-your-sources-list/857433#857433